# how can I test in Java if an Object exists at specific index?

Tags: java, arraylist

I use Arraylist and inserting Objects to specific index.(for example is element at index of 0 and 2 but it is not at at index of 1)And I want to know if I should use `Arraylist.add(id,obj)` or `Arraylist.set(id,obj)` . I use the following test `if(Arraylist.get(t.imgIdx) == null)` , but it throws me Exception out of bounds all the time. How can/should I test it?

```
public static int GiveBackAverageID(Vector<DMatch> lista){

        ArrayList<CMatch> workingList = new ArrayList<CMatch>();

        for (DMatch t : lista){
            if(workingList.get(t.imgIdx) == null){
                workingList.add(t.imgIdx, new CMatch(t.imgIdx,t.distance,1));
            }else{
                CMatch pom = workingList.get(t.imgIdx);
                pom.setSummaDist(pom.getSummaDist()+t.distance);
                pom.setCount(pom.getCount()+1);
                workingList.set(t.imgIdx, pom);
            }
        }
...
```

thanks
Csabi

Comment: Use add() to add elements and Use Iterator to traverse the elements

Comment: How do you retrieve the index of your elements? What values can they be?

Comment: I added the code where I have problem pls chceck it it should answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test if an object is at a position, use [`IndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29). This method returns -1 if the object is not in the list.

*UPDATE*

On your new piece of code:

```
public static int GiveBackAverageID(Vector<DMatch> lista){

    ArrayList<CMatch> workingList = new ArrayList<CMatch>();

    for (DMatch t : lista){
        if(t.imgIdx >= workingList.size() || t.imgIdx < 0)
        {
            // do something with wrong indices.
        }
        else
        {
            if(workingList.get(t.imgIdx) == null){
                workingList.add(t.imgIdx, new CMatch(t.imgIdx,t.distance,1));
            }else{
                CMatch pom = workingList.get(t.imgIdx);
                pom.setSummaDist(pom.getSummaDist()+t.distance);
                pom.setCount(pom.getCount()+1);
                workingList.set(t.imgIdx, pom);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or what you could also do, is generate more capacity in your `workingList`:

```
public static int GiveBackAverageID(Vector<DMatch> lista){

    // Creating more capacity in the constructor!
    ArrayList<CMatch> workingList = new ArrayList<CMatch>(lista.size());

    for (DMatch t : lista){
        if(workingList.get(t.imgIdx) == null){
            workingList.add(t.imgIdx, new CMatch(t.imgIdx,t.distance,1));
        }else{
            CMatch pom = workingList.get(t.imgIdx);
            pom.setSummaDist(pom.getSummaDist()+t.distance);
            pom.setCount(pom.getCount()+1);
            workingList.set(t.imgIdx, pom);
        }
    }
}
```

As a better alternative, I would use a **`HashTable<int,DMatch>`** instead.

Comment: Arraylist.get(index) == null  <== that test I wanna know not the indexOf(Obj), the object is not the same so i could not use it for the test.

Comment: make sure you have correctly implemented [equals() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

use set to replace at a specific index, and add to add object at the end, and add with index value to insert object at position and move other elements to right (adding one to their index).

Out of bounds exception means your index value is, probably, to large; or the arraylist has not been populated as you expect.  Post the full exception/code for a complete answer.

Comment: I know but that was not the question, I wanna know if is element at specific index or if it is NULL

Comment: `add(obj,ind)` inserts the object between the other elements and pushes the elements behind it back. `set(obj,ind)` replaces the object at `ind`.

Comment: I know what it means (out of bounds) it is not object at index, but how can I test it without getting the exception

Comment: Marnix, I know how works .add() and .set() I just can not figure out how can I test if in specific index is object or not(for example if at index of 1 is object, than i use .set() and if not than I use .add())

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to check the size of the list before you try to insert.  If the index is less than the list size, then you should be ok to check to see if it is null, otherwise, you always want to add a new element

Comment: You are not right because I can add element at the index of 1,2 and 5 and the size will be only 3

Comment: Array list is backed by an object array.  The size is the number of elements in the array.  YOu can have nulls, but that **does** take up an index and the size will take this into account

Comment: Ok,you are right(I upvote you :)), but eithe way this is not the answer for my questin, i do not need the size i need something like isObjectAtIndex(id) or somethink like that, but the arraylist does not have that method

Comment: '
if ( list.size() < index && list.get(index) != null)  { 
 // list element is not empty
} else {
  // list element is empty
}'

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code is that `t.imgIdx` value is sometimes greater than the array size.

But when you access the element (which is supposed to be null) like the code you did
 `if(workingList.get(t.imgIdx) == null)`, your if condition will return boolean value provided that the parameter passed to get() is less than the size of the array.

You can try the below example and pass different parameter values to get() method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.add(0, "5");
    al.add(1, "10");
    al.add(2, "15");
    al.add(3, "20");

    al.set(1, null);//setting the element at index 1 to NULL.
    //al.remove(1);//removes the element in list so that the next element's index decreases by 1. 

    if(al.get(1) == null){
        System.out.println("Nothing here..");//this line executes
    }
    else
        System.out.println(al.get(1));

}
```

Comment: Of course at the first test the size is 0. (for example if the first t.imgIdx is 7 the size is 0) what sould I do? add some fake object at index = 1000000 to generate big arraylist?

Comment: ok, then add an if condition that if t.imgldx less than array size, then proceed to the actual logic.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the Exception and handle it properly, it says that there is no element with this index.

Comment: It was not my questin, I can catch exception